# Is setting a vh the right way to make a background in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a question, I have been doing this all this time while learning, but i was always wondering, considering no tutorial I have seen uses any coloured background, they all use white and maybe color the div as a part of the page, but not whole. I want to color the whole background, I have been doing it this way.

- I set a div as a parent container;
- I set 100vh in css file;
- I color it via background-color property in css;

My question is, is this a valid way, any pros and cons and what other way u suggest. I only want to color background on a web page. For example Home component, not every other, just this one.

If it's not can u advise me with a right way please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same container `<div>...</div>` for the whole app where you use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for example, you can use `[ng-class]` to specify a class with the `background-color` and apply it only if the `router.url` is `/home`

```
<div class="container-fluid"
     [ng-class]="{'bg-home': router.url === '/home'}">
     ...
</div>
```

and for the css:

```
.bg-home {
   background-color: #0e0e0e;
}
```